# Collaboration graph

Tags: soft-question, sociology-of-math

Does anyone know a tool for drawing collaboratation graphs?

To be more specific, when you enter a new field (subfields) you would like to know who is who in this subfield which publications are pivotal in the fields etc. A mathematician can use tools like arXiv, mathsci.net or Google scholar. They are great but also a bit limited. I think it would be great to have a possibility to draw graphs which depicts connections.

I found such tool: http://pubnet.gersteinlab.org/gallery.html , but it works only for publications in medicine. Anything like that in math?

Comment: I don't think that this is about _actual research mathematics_ so am voting to close as off-topic.  I've grafted it on to a meta discussion <http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/667/who-is-not-a-descendant-of-gauss-or-euler> as I think it's related to the genealogy question.  I want to add that I had a lot of fun producing both a genealogy graph and a collaboration graph for the department at Sheffield a few years ago and still have all my scripts so if someone _actually_ wants to do this, they can contact me for the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

In the ISI [Web of Science](http://isiknowledge.com/WOS) you can have a citation graph for any paper in their database. Apparently this is as close as you can get to what you want for mathematics. Some general discussion on collaboration graph for the entire math community built using the MathSciNet data can be found [here](http://www.oakland.edu/enp/trivia/).

Also, consider using the [mathematical genealogy](http://www.genealogy.ams.org/) (the output of which can be visualised through graphs [here](http://www.ricam.oeaw.ac.at/people/page/labs/genealogy/genealogy_graphs.php)) and the [collaboration distance](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/collaboration.html) tools.